# can not make Shiny modules work with valueBox

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using shiny modules with some charts and everything works fine (amazing functionality!), ... but I can not make them work with valueBox (from shinydashboard). Nothing is rendered...
Here is a minimal example:

```
library(shinydashboard)

# MODULE UI
bsc_tile_UI <- function(id) {
   ns <- NS(id)
   valueBoxOutput("tile1", width=12)
}

# MODULE Server
bsc_tile_OUT <- function(input, output, session, number, metric) {
  output$tile1 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(number, paste(metric), icon = icon("arrow-up"),color = "blue", 
    width=12)
  })
}

ui<-dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
      sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
      dashboardBody(
        fluidPage(
          bsc_tile_UI("tile_1"),
          bsc_tile_UI("tile_2")
          )
        )
      )

# App server
server <- function(input, output,session){  
  callModule(bsc_tile_OUT, "tile_1", '300', 'metric 1')
  callModule(bsc_tile_OUT, "tile_2", '500', 'metric 2')
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the given example parameteres "number" and "metric" are explicitly provided, but my intention is they will be defined as variables of a dataframe.

Any help will be welcome!!!
(sorry my english)

Comment: Have you tried using renderUI() instead of renderValueBox? It's a workaround, but it might solve your problem.

Comment: No succes using renderUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ns()` in all your defined Module inputs. The module server is taking the members of the output vector and will internally attach the module ID to them ("tile_1" and "tile_2" in your case) - this is what you need to do manually in UI by using `ns()`. So if you just change your module UI output definition to the following, your code will work:

`valueBoxOutput(ns("tile1"), width=12)`

[image]

Comment: shosaco, you saved my day! It worked perfectly.  thanks!